# Lua version at runtime

Tags: lua, c-api

I am trying to make a fat runtime library (in C) for lua using ifunc attribute, to do so i need the lua version from the C api at runtime for my resolver function.

I know there are the _VERSION stored somewhere in the global table but i can't rely use any lua function before knowing in what version my code is executed

I tried to memmem the lua state in search for the version without any luck, maybe there is a simpler way

Comment: Are you writing the library in Lua? If so, why can't you rely on `_VERSION` at the time of evaluation? `_VERSION` is not a function, it's a reserved variable.

Comment: no, i am writting a C library, as such to access it i need to access the global variable in the lua_state witch is unfortunately not the same between 5.1 and 5.3 and i am unable to access without knowing the version

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you'll have to compile the C library for 5.1 and 5.3 separately due to the linkage, or are you dynamically linking to Lua through i.e. `dlopen`? In that case, you could `dlsym` `lua_version` - https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_version

Comment: yes, i will have separate library for each lua version compiled separately, then i want a wrapper library which will call the right version depending of the lua interpreter which will use it (through `require "wrapperlib"`)

Comment: lua_version is exactly what i need, but don't exist for lua5.1 : (

Comment: I see, that's problematic indeed. You could `lua_getglobal` the `_VERSION` value from the state, is there a reason why you don't want to use that?